# How to get an item from a document in Firebase storage and adding it to a view with SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to get the variable "name" from a Firestore document (UserProfileVC) and adding it to a header (UserProfileHeader) but I am having issues with getting the data in the format that I need. Currently I am getting the error message below for the "userReference.getDocument { (snapshot) in" line in UserProfileVC. I have tried it several different ways but nothing I have tried has worked. What am I doing wrong or is there a better way that I can organize the data? I am new to SWIFT so my solution may be way off!

**Error Message:**

> Contextual closure type '(DocumentSnapshot?, Error?) -> Void' expects
>   2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

**Model - User Class:**

```
class User{

    var username: String!
    var name: String!
    var uid: String!

    init(uid: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        self.uid = uid
        if let username = dictionary["username"] as? String {
            self.username = username
        }
        if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        }
    }
```

**View - UserProfileHeader:**

```
var user: User? {
        didSet {
            let fullName = user?.name
            nameLabel.text = fullName

            guard let profileImageUrl = user?.profileImageUrl else { return }
            profileImageView.loadImage(with: profileImageUrl)
        }
    }
```

**Controller - UserProfileVC:**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader

        header.delegate = self

        header.user = self.user
        navigationItem.title = user?.username

        return header
    }

func fetchCurrentUserData() {

    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userReference = db.collection("profile_data").document(currentUid)

    userReference.getDocument { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
        let uid = snapshot.key
        let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
        self.user = user
        self.navigationItem.title = user.username
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Modify your entire code inside the `fetchCurrentUserData` to align with the new Firbase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift_1).

Inside the method `fetchCurrentUserData` the closure `userReference.getDocument` has two parameter instead of one just modify that and you're good, here's how:

```
func fetchCurrentUserData() {
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userReference = db.collection("profile_data").document(currentUid)

    userReference.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dictionary = document.data()
            let uid = snapshot.key
            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
            self.user = user
            self.navigationItem.title = user.username
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar before and got the same errors that you solution produce which are "Expression type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?' is ambiguous without more context" and "Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot?' has no member 'key'". How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Check the update. I've updated the code to some extend but, your database structure is unfamiliar to me, I've added the documentation link too check it out to see the new changes, your code seems outdated.

Comment: I agree it is not the best format. I originally tried to use the Firestore format that you sent in the update but I could not get it to work. I have updated my original function for fetchCurrentUserData. I guess I should really be trying to update my User and UserProfileHeader view. Do you have any suggestions on how I should do that?